# Printing a list justified with format

Tags: python, format

I just learned from this answer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6335836/2474231) I can use `format` with a list:

```
li = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
print '{0} {2} {1} {4}'.format(*li) # => 2 5 3 11
```

Now I want to justify every element of a list. What I'm doing is:

```
print "{0:>12}{1:>12}{2:>12}{3:>12}".format(*PROPERTIES)
```

However, this isn't really convenient as the list may get larger. I am curious is this possible by using only `print` and `format` (no loops)?

Comment: which out put you expected to see ??????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
print ('{:>12}'*len(li)).format(*li) 
        2           3           5           7          11
```

Comment: What is the `"".join` for? Doesn't that just take the string apart and put it back together?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can `map` the same `str.format` to every item, then `str.join` the results together:

```
>>> li = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
>>> print "".join(map("{0:>12}".format, li))
           2           3           5           7          11
```

Indeed, having looked, this is *exactly what's done* in the answer you linked to.